# Writing a list of lists to file, removing unwanted characters and a new line for each

Tags: csv, format, sublist

I have a list "newdetails" that is a list of lists and it needs to be written to a csv file. Each field needs to take up a cell (without the trailing characters and commas) and each sublist needs to go on to a new line.

The code I have so far is:

```
file = open(s + ".csv","w")
    file.write(str(newdetails))
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
```

This however, writes to the csv in the following, unacceptable format:

```
[['12345670'     'Iphone 9.0'    '500'  2    '3'     '5']    ['12121212'     'Samsung Laptop'    '900'  4    '3'     '5']]
```

The format I wish for it to be in is as shown below:

```
12345670    Iphone 9.0  500 5   3   5
12121212    Samsung Laptop  900 5   3   5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` module to write information to csv file.

Please check below links:

- [csv module in Python 2](https://pymotw.com/2/csv/)
- [csv module in Python 3](https://pymotw.com/3/csv/)

**Code:**

```
import csv

new_details = [['12345670','Iphone 9.0','500',2,'3','5'],
               ['12121212','Samsung Laptop','900',4,'3','5']]
import csv
with open("result.csv","w",newline='') as fh

writer = csv.writer(fh,delimiter=' ')

for data in new_details:
    writer.writerow(data)
```

**Content of result.csv:**

```
12345670 "Iphone 9.0" 500 2 3 5
12121212 "Samsung Laptop" 900 4 3 5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659083/updating-a-multiple-value-running-total-in-python

Comment: Just saw your comment. Will check in couple of minutes.

Comment: It is driving me literally crazy! It's basically something to do with - how do I make the dictionary values (drawn from these two running totals) tally up.

Comment: Going through it. Its long post and it is in bits and pieces. :)

Comment: I will literally want to buy you a present if you help me solve it!